# How does a browser render the actual pixels

Tags: browser, rendering, html-rendering

I am looking for an explanation about how a browser renders / paints the actual pixels on your screen.
I found this answer that contains this great image on how a browser goes from html and css to an actual representation on the screen.

[image]

But this doesnt explain me how the actual painting step is implemented. So how is the actual frame tree painted?

Is it done with vertex buffers and shaders?

> **For example**: A div could be rendered by creating a quad and then render this quad with a shader that for example adds a border, rounded corners etc to the div depending on the styling?

Or is there some other technique used?

And how would this be done with long pieces of text? Generating a quad for each letter doesnt sound very performant?

Let me know if extra context or clarification is needed!

Comment: It depends on the browser, and the version of the browser.
This is a great article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/the-whole-web-at-maximum-fps-how-webrender-gets-rid-of-jank/

Comment: Quite an awesome article! So i guess it is done with shaders and vertex buffers in the end.

Comment: @clankill3r if you post it as an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the browser, and the version of the browser. [This is a great article.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/10/the-whole-web-at-maximum-fps-how-webrender-gets-rid-of-jank/)